# sorting an array between array and string values

Tags: php, sorting

I am creating a template parser and i need to sort the array of variables that gets passed into the parser so that each array element that IS an array get processed first. For example:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'Steven',
    'type' => array(
        'gender' => 'M',
        'age' => 23'
    )
)
```

I need 'type' to be first since it is an array, and 'name' to be last. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? Ive looked at php.net's manual at the different sort functions, but dont see how any apply to my situation.

Comment: The order makes no sense in hashes

Comment: what do you mean hashes?

Comment: The kind of collection where the values are referenced by strings - is a hash. The collection where the values referenced by numerical index - an array.

Comment: what im looking for is if 'name' is a string, put it to the back of the array, and if 'type' is an array, move it to the front, and so on and so on.

Comment: because if the parser does arrays first, then you can have something like this: {array_block} {insde_array_var} {{outside_var}} {/array_block}

Comment: You don't need to sort the array to do that though, just pass through it twice, first time processing arrays and second time parsing single values. That's actually less work than sorting then passing through once.

Comment: really? Even if you pass an enormous ammount of variables into the parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
   return is_array($a)? -1 : 0;
}

uasort($data, "cmp");
```

Comment: very nice :) ... looks clean and easy

Comment: This is absolutely wrong. It will put the arrays AFTER non-arrays.

Comment: You are absolutely right, AlienWebguy! Thanks! Fixed my post based on your comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return is_array($a) ? -1 : 1;
}    
uasort($data, "cmp");
```

This will sort the array based on the value type...alphabetically. Array comes before String.

Comment: I fixed your comparison of $a to $a, and changed the sorting function to uasort so you don't wipe out all his array keys, and simplified your comparison as you don't really need all those branches.